# Ought I add salt to water bottles, if I'm putting the bottles in front of a fan to improvise an air conditioner?

Tags: salt

1. Is [this advice](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Easy-Homemade-Air-Conditioner-from-a-Fan-and-Water-Bottles) correct? Are they alluding to Freezing Point Depression? Adding salt to tap water lowers the [Crystalloid](https://www.easybiologyclass.com/difference-between-colloids-and-crystalloids-a-comparison-table/)'s freezing point.

> **Pour 3 tbsp (51 g) of salt into each of your 3 plastic water bottles.** Use disposable plastic bottles for the easiest set-up and clean up. Pour 3 tablespoons (51 g) of table salt per bottle. Put the caps back on and shake the bottles to thoroughly mix the salt.

2. I live in a studio flat. I know of the [Law of Thermodynamics](https://old.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3cuekw/is_a_diy_air_conditioner_a_thermodynamically_good/cszsr8j/), also [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/utuw2/would_a_homemade_air_cooler_that_uses_cooper/c4yhbug/)  – but my plan is different. Where I live, night time is way cooler than day time. I'll freeze the bottles over night, because even if my freezer heats up more than usual, my night room temperature will still be cool enough. During day time when it's hot, I'll place the frozen bottles  in front of my fan to air condition my studio flat. Does this work? [I read Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-putting-a-frozen-water-bootle-in-front-on-a-fan-make-it-move-colder-air-around-the-room).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense physically, but the question is if you would have enough bottles for that for sufficient effect.

Twice water  heat capacity than ice about compensate lower amount of water, so it can be considered about the same.

The major effect is increased heat transfer keeping it colder for most of the time, as melting, absorbing the most of heat, would occur at lower temperature. Also, liquid provides better heat transfer due convection.

The strongest effect would be using as much salt for solution to still get frozen in the freezer.

About 330 g / 1 L water makes solution with freezing point near $\pu{-20^{\circ}C}$.
50 g / 1.5L PET would be like $\pu{-2^{\circ}C}$.

If we take the heat for ice melting as 100%, water warming up by $\pu{12^{\circ}C}$ takes  15% and ice warming up by $\pu{16^{\circ}C}$ takes just 10%. Shifting melting point by $\pu{2^{\circ}C}$ causes increasing total water heat capacity by 1.25%.